# Twitter advanced search

Tags: java, search, twitter4j

I am using twitter4j to mine tweets from the twitter search Api. My problem is that I cannot exclude words that contain an apostrophe from the result set. For instance if I write a query like this..

```
Query query = new Query("castles -hasn't");
```

it will still return tweets that contain the word hasn't. It works for words that don't contain an apostrophe. Can anybody help me fix this ?

Comment: Probably need to escape the apostrophe but don't quote me on that.

Answer (score 0):

Encoding the query string solved a similar problem for me...

`"castles -hasn't"` ⇨ `"castles%20-hasn%27t"`